# How can I know big O notation from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, big-o

this is an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) from PostgreSQL

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=245.73..292.69 rows=1174 width=46) (actual time=38.850..39.454 rows=148 loops=1)
  Group Key: location_id, (date_trunc('day'::text, created_at)), payment_method
  ->  Sort  (cost=245.73..248.66 rows=1174 width=42) (actual time=38.829..38.916 rows=1100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: location_id, (date_trunc('day'::text, created_at)), payment_method
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 165kB
        ->  Seq Scan on payment p  (cost=0.00..185.87 rows=1174 width=42) (actual time=1.905..6.849 rows=1100 loops=1)
              Filter: ((location_id IS NOT NULL) AND (created_at <= '2019-04-23 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at >= '2000-04-23 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ((entity_type)::text = 'RESERVATION'::text) AND ((payment_status)::text = ANY ('{SUCCESS,CAPTURE,REFUNDED}'::text[])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2238
Planning Time: 1.895 ms
Execution Time: 39.727 ms
```

This is my query code

```
select  p.location_id,
        date_trunc('day', p.created_at) as date,
        p.payment_method,
        count(p.id), sum(p.sub_amount)+sum(p.mdr_fee)+sum(p.convenience_fee) as GrossSales,
        sum(p.sub_amount) netSales
from payment p
where p.location_id is not null
  and p.entity_type = 'RESERVATION'
  and p.payment_status in ('SUCCESS','CAPTURE','REFUNDED')
  and created_at <= '2019-04-23'
  and created_at >= '2000-04-23'
group by p.location_id, date, p.payment_method
order by p.location_id asc, date asc, p.payment_method;
```

I don't know how to see the big O notation EXPLAIN (ANALYZE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see the “big O notation” in `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`.

It is not something that you can see in a single data point, it is a description how certain parameters of the input data (e.g., the size of a table) will affect the run time of a certain algorithm. This can be measured by using the same algorithm for different input data, but usually it is determined by analyzing the algorithm.

For example, the sequential scan has an expense of O(n), where n is the size of the table. That means that it will take roughly twice as long for a table that is twice as big. The cost of a sort is O(n⋅ln(n)), where “ln” is a logarithm, which means that it will be notably more than twice as expensive for a set twice the size.

Measurements (like `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`) are not a great way to determine such numbers, because there are always different factors coming in (like caching) that will obscure the numbers. Also, you don't want a guess that the expense *might* be O(n), you want a mathematical proof.

Comment: can i know the complexity from query i make in this case?

Comment: Only if you read the source code and understand the algorithms.